# Create ranges with CASE statemant - ERROR: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count, range, case

I'm tring to create ranges using `CASE` but I have a problem with counting the numbers of appearances. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN engine_capacity < 1 THEN 'less than 1'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 1 AND engine_capacity <= 2 THEN '1.0 - 2.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 2 AND engine_capacity < 3 THEN '2.0 - 3.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 3 AND engine_capacity < 4 THEN '3.0 - 4.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 4 AND engine_capacity < 5 THEN '4.0 - 5.0'
    ELSE 'more than 5' 
    END AS 'Range',
    COUNT(1) AS 'Count'
FROM cars
GROUP BY 'Range';
```

and I have an error:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: you can't group by alias. you have to copypaste your case when thing. Also, don't use strings as aliases, [quotes] is better

Comment: Don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use T-SQL's identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: In this case `GROUP BY 'Range'` means group by the *literal string* `'Range'`, which doesn't make sense, how can you group by a literal value? That's why you're being told you need your expression to contain an outer reference, as the string `'Range'` is just that; a string.

Comment: Thank, I'll keep in mind tips about aliases and ("").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the full `CASE` statement in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN engine_capacity < 1 THEN 'less than 1'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 1 AND engine_capacity <= 2 THEN '1.0 - 2.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 2 AND engine_capacity < 3 THEN '2.0 - 3.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 3 AND engine_capacity < 4 THEN '3.0 - 4.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 4 AND engine_capacity < 5 THEN '4.0 - 5.0'
    ELSE 'more than 5' 
    END AS [Range],
    COUNT(1) AS [Count]
FROM cars
GROUP BY 
    CASE
        WHEN engine_capacity < 1 THEN 'less than 1'
        WHEN engine_capacity >= 1 AND engine_capacity <= 2 THEN '1.0 - 2.0'
        WHEN engine_capacity >= 2 AND engine_capacity < 3 THEN '2.0 - 3.0'
        WHEN engine_capacity >= 3 AND engine_capacity < 4 THEN '3.0 - 4.0'
        WHEN engine_capacity >= 4 AND engine_capacity < 5 THEN '4.0 - 5.0'
        ELSE 'more than 5' 
    END
```

Or, use a subquery before grouping:

```
SELECT 
    [Range], 
    count(*) as [Count]
from
(
    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN engine_capacity < 1 THEN 'less than 1'
        WHEN engine_capacity >= 1 AND engine_capacity <= 2 THEN '1.0 - 2.0'
        WHEN engine_capacity >= 2 AND engine_capacity < 3 THEN '2.0 - 3.0'
        WHEN engine_capacity >= 3 AND engine_capacity < 4 THEN '3.0 - 4.0'
        WHEN engine_capacity >= 4 AND engine_capacity < 5 THEN '4.0 - 5.0'
        ELSE 'more than 5' 
        END AS [Range]
    FROM cars
) a
GROUP BY [Range]
```

Comment: I've personally found the subquery option to be faster. And, its easier to add to a debug later.

Comment: Yes, thank. I used subquery, it's shorter and looks better.

Answer (score -3):

```sql
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN engine_capacity < 1 THEN 'less than 1'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 1 AND engine_capacity <= 2 THEN '1.0 - 2.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 2 AND engine_capacity < 3 THEN '2.0 - 3.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 3 AND engine_capacity < 4 THEN '3.0 - 4.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 4 AND engine_capacity < 5 THEN '4.0 - 5.0'
    ELSE 'more than 5' 
    END AS 'Range',
    COUNT(1) AS 'Count'
FROM cars
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN engine_capacity < 1 THEN 'less than 1'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 1 AND engine_capacity <= 2 THEN '1.0 - 2.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 2 AND engine_capacity < 3 THEN '2.0 - 3.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 3 AND engine_capacity < 4 THEN '3.0 - 4.0'
    WHEN engine_capacity >= 4 AND engine_capacity < 5 THEN '4.0 - 5.0'
    ELSE 'more than 5' 
    END
```

Comment: Maybe try formatting your solution to make it easier to read.